# Importing a .CSV file into existing table in SQL Server 2000 database from the command line

Tags: csv, command-line, sql-server-2000

I wrote a C# program that will take a `.CSV` file and insert its data into an up to date `.MDF` file (SQL Server 2014), checking that the data is not already in the database file.

It works well enough with the modern instance of SQL Server, however I need to do the same thing to a database that is running SQL Server 2000. It comes up saying the database cannot be updated/upgraded, and I cannot get SQL Server Management Studio to install because of how old the PC is, blah blah blah.

A friend mentioned using the command line to do it much more simply than writing code. Is this possible? if so, then how exactly? I saw some articles that are similar to what I want to do, but not exactly...

Comment: I'd question why you'd have to work with a database that is 16 years old . Even SQL 2005 is now out of extended support and is no longer being updated by Microsoft. Is there not a way you can upgrade this database?

Comment: The client is stubborn and won't do it.